# Ways to lay this cyrstal out without increasing the PCB footprint?

Tags: layout, crystal

I am trying to follow the best practises in laying out a crystal.
Namely:
1. Keep traces short and direct
2. Keep it as close to the pins
3. Keep-out region under the crystal
4. No vias
5. Isolate the crystal

However I cannot fit my bypass caps near the pins.
Before I change the footprint of the PCB to accommodate the requirement, is there anything I can do to make my current design work?

[update]

The MCU is ATMEGA34U4. Crystals is [this](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/txc-corporation/7B-16.000MAAJ-T/887-1104-1-ND/2118981)

Matching capacitors are 18pF (as per the datasheet in the link).

[image: Not enough space]

[Update #2]
The following is what I came up with. Thank you all for your eyes on this!

[image: Update]

Comment: May I know which software is this?

Comment: How critical are your layout contraints?  What frequency are you running at?

Comment: Do you have matching capacitors to oscillator's load capacitance?

Comment: @Whiskeyjack it is CircuitMaker

Comment: @Wossname the frequency of the crystal is 16Mghz. I just want the best quality layout decisions. I will have to increase the PCB footprint if I don't figure it out.

Comment: @Haris778 I added more info in the post. The capacitors, according to the datasheet of crystal, should be 18nF.

Comment: @b1gtuna, sometimes the best decision is to get close enough to ideal without giving yourself a whole heap more work to do.  ATMegas are very tolerant of imperfect xtal placements.  What you have here is more than good enough.

Comment: Are you sure about that 18 *n*F? Crystal load capacitors from MHz crystals are mostly in the 10-30 *p*F range..

Comment: Totally unrelated to your question, but have you considerd using a creamic resonator instead of a crystal? Has built-in capacitors, is cheaper, more shock-resistant... and OK, less accurate.

Comment: Why wouldn't you angle your bypass caps @ 45° so that they're closer to the ends they need to connect with? I guess they have one leg in the ground plane and the other connected to the active crystal pins, right?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen 18pF it is! I misread from the datasheet. I have not considered a ceramic resonator. I already have the parts sitting in my drawer.

Comment: @Wossname Ok thank for your comment. I really hope this works. I may adjust the placement of the capacitors slightly at the most.

Comment: @Nasha Good suggestion. Let me put them at 45 degrees.

Comment: I forgot to mention something ctritical. If i route D0 to D3 in the bottom layer, underneath the crystal, would that be a problem? It is not ideal, I am aware.

Comment: @b1gtuna, that won't be a problem.  Have a **very** close look at your crystal component (literally get a magnifying glass) - you'll notice that it has a very tiny PCB forming the bottom part.  That tiny PCB will have a GND plane inside it, shielding your xtal from any signals below.

Comment: @Wossname Thanks. Even though it won't make much difference, I have update the layout with the traces going around the crystal. It is in the original post above. Please take a look. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your layout looks almost perfect already. If you had place, you could place everything a little bit better, but the influence is so tiny, you will never spot the difference.

Remember, you can built this circuit with THT components on a breadboard and it still works. 16 MHz is not really a lot on a PCB. Trace lengths and length matching are not that important at these frequencies. In any case, make sure that the ground connection is good all around the crystal.

What I would do:

- move the component right above the crystal to the right
- move one capacitor in the now free space, leave the other where it is.

Comment: Thanks for your vote of confidence! I will incorporate your suggestions. I have one remaining question. If I route D0 to D3  in the bottom layer, directly underneath the crystal , do you think it is still ok? I would like to avoid signal coupling to the traces, but I guess I need to make compromises.

Comment: This depends on what these signals are. Do you expect them to change often? If it's a single layer board, you can't provide a good ground connection to the crystal if these traces are below. Maybe move the crystal a bit further to the right to make space for the four traces to run on the left side of the crystal.

Comment: Thank you. I have routed them around the crystal to avoid coupling. Please see my updated post. Thank you!